# if statement on images

Tags: java, android

I have an image that is a tick. At the moment i know how to set visibilty using GONE/VISIBLE.

```
    tick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I want to be able to detect whether an image is visible using an if statement.

```
if (tick is visible){
i++
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (View.VISIBLE == tick.getVisibility()) {
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you.

```
if (ticket.getVisiblity() == View.VISIBLE) {
   i++;
}
```